# Slow performance due to "Parallel WHERE evaluation suppressed due to sort order on table" & compression type

Tags: multithreading, performance, sas

We have a reasonably large dataset (about 700GB) which is in a SPDE library and it contains the SORTEDBY option.  Unfortunately it seems that this option causes a massive performance drop and looks like it defaults back to using a single thread.

Is there any way of overriding this to force SAS to use the maximum CPU threads to read this dataset?  The sort order is not important for my purposes.  I have looked at the SPDSEV2T option on http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/spdsug/67140/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1fru1udmbaf6xn1ta8u681lp6fu.htm but the documentation is poor and doesn't seem to do anything.

Note we are using SAS 9.4.

Also note this is a production dataset so cannot overwrite/replace the original table and that is it compressed in BINARY format.

Thanks in advance

Below is an example with stats and code:

Table has 300 million rows and 870 columns.  Table size is 823GB using CHAR compression.  Table size is 638GB using BINARY compression

The data step below takes 1 hour and 30 minutes using the BINARY compression table.  Looks like the gimped performance is due to it going to single thread mode for some strange reason.  Disk reading speed = 50mb/sec

The data step below takes 14 minutes using the CHAR compression table.  All CPUs are active in this step.  Disk reading speed = 1000mb/sec.

Using fullstimer there was a difference between the 2 compression methods. BINARY had "Block Input Operations = 0", while CHAR had "Block Input Operations = 7616".  However not sure if that means anything.

```
libname hs2 SPDE '/work/saswork/spde'; 

DATA table1 (KEEP=cp b pl ii ex exy fred sta n ee qwe ver pot gr pcr burb)
     table3 (KEEP=b pt cl sb n sd ed yt ta cl sb cp pcr burb)
     table2 (KEEP=b pt cl sb n sd ed yt ta cl sb cp pcr burb);
   SET hs2.bigtable_char (    
   KEEP=cp b pl ii ex exy fred sta n ee qwe ver poy gr pcr burb
        pt cl sb  sd ed yt ta
   WHERE=(cl= 'YTR' and sb = 'IYU' and cp in (2,47,101,45)));
   IF (sd <= "&end."d <= ed AND ti /*ti is a numeric variable*/ AND ta not in ('A' 'B' 'C')) THEN OUTPUT table3;
   IF (sd <= "&middle."d <= ed AND ti AND ta not in ('A' 'B' 'C')) THEN     OUTPUT table2;
   IF (fred >= "&start."d and fred <= "&end."d) THEN OUTPUT table1;
RUN;
```

Comment: Sounds like a question for SAS Support.  Can you provide some sample code ?  In DEV machine, do you get the same message on much smaller table with same features as the big one ?

Comment: Thanks Richard I will give them a try.  Forgot my password to for SAS support sight and taking forever to get my password reset

Comment: And yes I notice the same message and bad performance on smaller data also (I tried using a 20 million row subset)

Comment: Do you get the same message if you move the where clause from the WHERE= option to a WHERE statement below the SET statement ?  If you drop to 30M rows do you get the same ? I ask, because at 30M you probably can try same with no-compression.  If the compression is the cause .... disk $ < ram $ < time $.  Might need to spend some time $ with SAS Admin or Support to make sure the libname options or server setup are using best practice settings for your hardware and datasets.

Comment: Yep get the same message when changing from the WHERE= option to the WHERE statement.  I tried removing the SORTEDBY option which gets rid of the message but the performance issue still remains

Comment: What does the `DS2` libnames statement look like ?  It could be possible the output I/O is making the step slow,  `OPTIONS FULLSTIMER` before the step will display more info. Try the step as `DATA _null_` -- then the step is only reading `bigtable` and you can see it's contribution to performance. You can also get a lot more (Windows) detailed diagnostics using perfmon to examine counters in the SAS object.

Comment: The libname is
libname hs2 SPDE '/work/saswork/spde';
Using your fullstimer suggestion there was a difference between the 2 compression methods.  BINARY had "Block Input Operations = 0", while CHAR had "Block Input Operations = 7616"

Comment: Edit the question and place the additional information in there, instead of in comments.